# "With" statement equivalent for Scala?

Tags: scala

Idle pondering from a Scala learner perhaps, but ... in my tinkerings I've written the following:

```
( n.child.size > 0 ) && ( n.child.filter( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ).size == 0 )
```

('n' is a scala.xml.Node, but that's not important.  Nor is the particular logic.)

Calling child() twice isn't so good, so I was about to change it:

```
val list = n.child
( list.size > 0 ) && ( list.filter( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ).size == 0 )
```

But given how much I've come to much appreciate being able to filter() and map() and such without needing to declare intermediate variables, I found this immediately smelly.  It's so... so... so Java-ish! :p

Alas, digging through SO and Google and the ScalaDocs (especially Any and AnyRef) and The Book has turned up nothing appropriate.  I was hoping perhaps for something like:

```
n.child{ list => ( list.size > 0 ) && ( list.filter( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ).size == 0 ) }
```

or even

```
n.child.with{ list => ... }
```

Does something like this exist?  Or am I just getting caught up in a variable-less-ness fervour?

Comment: Also, that filter/size thing is inefficient. Replace it with 
list.forall(_.isInstanceOf[Text])

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but it's not quite the same thing:  I need to know that the list contains only Text elements AND is non-empty.  

I just found Iterable's "count" which can shorten things a bit:  
( n.child.size > 0 ) && ( n.child.count( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ) == 0 )

Comment: Even better:  ! ( n.child.isEmpty || n.child.exists( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ) )

Comment: sorry, wasn't clear.  I meant

!n.child.isEmpty && n.child.forall(_.isInstanceof[Text])

which is the same as your last one via DeMorgans Law and the fact that !x.exists(!y) is the same as x.forall(y)

Comment: I had the same problem, but then I learned that this kind of val usage can be quite beneficial and does not compare with java's *mutable* vars. Especially if you use a better name, in this case "val child = n.child", this makes the code much more obvious.

Comment: @DaveGriffith - Why not use `nonEmpty` instead of `! isEmpty`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"with" is, of course, a reserved word in Scala, so let's call it "let", from the similar binding form in Lisp and Haskell.   Turns out "let" is just a backwards way of writing function application.

```
def let[A,B](param:A)(body: A=>B):B = body(param)

let(n.child){list=> ...}
```

If the bound variable is used only once, you could of course use the anonymous function form, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Nice!  And now I've got a new bit of Scala syntax to puzzle through. :-)

Comment: You can also use pimp my library.

Comment: Isn't the same lenght as "val list = n.child" "list..."?

Comment: more precisely, it's equivalent to {val list = n.child; list...}, with the braces to make it a single expression.

Comment: it should be in standard library :)

Comment: for anyone who turns up seeking a Scala equivalent to *python's* `with` statement, this answer talks about something else more similar to Haskell's `let` or `with` bindings. Side note: I think this answer's comparison with function application breaks down for Haskell's `let` and `with` though, because those define a mutually recursive namespace, so you can have 'assignments' in a `let` block that recursively depend on each other (this is one way to do lazy dynamic programming in Haskell, for example).

Answer (score 21):

```
{
    import n.child._
    ( size > 0 ) && ( filter( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ).size == 0 )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
class Tap[A](underlying:A){
   def tap[B](func: A=>B) = func(underlying)
}

implicit def anyToTap[A](underlying:A)=new Tap(underlying)

n.child.tap{x =>
   ( x.size > 0 ) &&
   ( x.filter( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ).size == 0 )
}
```

Comment: There's now an implementation of Tap in this library: https://github.com/snowplow/scala-util

Comment: The `tap(A=>B)` method should probably be `tap(A=>Unit): A` to allow for further chaining or assignments, such as:
    `val order = new Order().tap { o =>
       o.setStatus('UNPAID')
    }`

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to limit the scope of your intermediate variable, you can also just create a block around the predicate:

```
val n = getNodeByMagic()
val passesTest = {
    val child = n.child
    child.length == 0 && !child.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Text]).isEmpty
}
// child is not defined outside of the block
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `match` for that purpose.

```
n.child match {
case list => ( list.size > 0 ) && ( list.filter( ! _.isInstanceOf[Text] ).size == 0 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library now provides a chaining operation method [`pipe`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B) fitting exactly this need:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

n.child.pipe(list => list.size > 0 && list.filterNot(_.isInstanceOf[Text]).size == 0)
```

The value of `n.child` is "piped" to the function of interest.